# Typo3 basic markers?

Tags: php, typo3

I have this typoscript:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEMPLATE
page.10.template = FILE
page.10.template.file = fileadmin/templates/index.html

page.10.marks{
# Marker TITLE
TITLE = TEXT
TITLE.field = title
}
```

And in my template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Here goes the title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>


<body>
<div id="headertitle">###TITLE###</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why this wouldn't work?
I mean I see the template on page show, but instead of title I get ###TITLE### shown

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. What's the error message in the admin panel?
2. Did you add a static template?

Comment: I don't get any message. I added a template file that's located: fileadmin/templates/index.html

Comment: Nothing red? Strange. Do you have added the default static template to your typoscript template? It's either content_style or css_content_style.

Comment: Well no, among include Static I can pick just CSS files, Fluid, Clickenlarge, DEFAULT TS (form). I haven't included any of them.

Comment: Your typoscript template. You need content_style or css_content_style.

Comment: Well I added content_style among includes. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. The variablename is ambigous. Did you tried another name? Did the title field is filled? Did you tried TITLE.value = TEST?

Comment: Btw. Don't forget to clear to frontend-cache and also the browser cache can be involved.

Answer (score 1):

Activate the `admin panel` with `config.admPanel = 1` at the very top of your `TypoScript`. This will put a small box at the lower left part of your frontend page.

Then open the `admin panel` and open the `TypoScript` subpart. Check all checkboxes except `Explain SELECT queries` and click update.
You should now see a full log on what `TYPO3` is doing with your `TypoScript`.

Another thing to check: Did you maybe accidentally add the `TypoScript` to the `constant` section instead of the `setup` section? Please verify with the `TS Object Browser` or the `Template Analyzer`.